# virtualenv: cannot install modules

Tags: python, module, pip, virtual, environment

I am trying to run some python scripts on HPC cluster. My scripts required some python modules that were not in the cluster and I do not have permission to install them (through `sudo`). This is why I created a `virtualenv` (in my directory on the HPC cluster). 
I successfully installed numpy but cannot insall: `re`, `collections`, `time`, `csv` and some more. 
The error that I get is this:
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for csv`
I am new to python and this seems completely weird to me, since I was following the steps found on two different sources.
What should I do to fix it? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That error usually means there are no packages with those names .

Actually, you do not need to install those packages ( they do not exist ). They are included in python's standard library. you should just import  them like :

```
import csv
import re
```

Comment: katrinaD if it works, you should accept it as the correct answer :)